# Flutter: Can't make a ClipPath

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Can someone help me with this ClipPath in Flutter?

I can't make the bottom border.

[image]

Also, how can I make it visible as a Row child?

I noticed that it works in Container, but it doesn't in when I drag the Container(or Flexible) in Row or without the widgets.

**UPDATE**

This is the return when the ClipPath is not visible

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: AuthClipPath(),
            child: Container(
            height: size.height * .75,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: gradient),
            child: authForm(),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

And this is the return when the ClipPath is visible

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: AuthClipPath(),
        child: Container(
        height: size.height * .75,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: gradient),
        child: authForm(),
      ),
    ),
  )       
)
```

This is clipper class from ClipPath

```
class AuthClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 30);

    Offset firstControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
    Offset firstPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstPoint.dx, firstPoint.dy);

    Offset secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width / 4 * 3, size.height);
    Offset secondPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height - 30);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

*The Flexible Widget is not relevant for the visibility.*

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share code for how its working and then how its not working?

Comment: I added the return code when it works and when it doesn't.


If providing the entire file will help, please say and I will create a Git Repo, but I don't think it is relevant, since this is the only change that I have to made for the ClipPath to be visible.


Thanks for looking on the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `AuthClipPath()` like this inside `Row()`

```
home: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: AuthClipPath(),
              child: Container(
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.amber.shade200,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

You can achieve the wave effect like this. And you can always tweak according to your needs.

```
Path path = Path();
path.moveTo(size.width, 0);
path.lineTo(0, 0);
path.quadraticBezierTo(
    0, size.height * 0.4500000, 0, size.height * 0.6000000);
path.cubicTo(
    size.width * 0.3000000,
    size.height * 0.9000000,
    size.width * 0.7000000,
    size.height * 0.3000000,
    size.width,
    size.height * 0.6000000);
path.quadraticBezierTo(
    size.width, size.height * 0.4500000, size.width, 0);
path.close();

return path;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I solved it right now:)

Apparently, was because an element from the authForm() went outside of the Row widget.

Do you know to make custom ClipPath? If you do, can you please help me with the Path from above?

Comment: Yes sure, check the code I have updated with your wave effect just paste those lines.